# jquery jStepper decimal not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the fantastic jQuery plugin [jStepper](http://jstepper.emkay.dk/default.aspx) in my MVC app for restricting a text box to numeric values.

The recent version 1.3.1 works well, except for `allowDecimals` and `decimalSeparator`. I am not sure if it's a browser issue, but it simply failed to work with all major browsers.

`allowDecimals = false` should prevent the user from entering decimal values, but it's not.

`decimalSperator = ","` should allow only the character `,` besides decimals, but it's not.

This is how I am using jStepper.
In my MVC Razor, I do have

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(b => b.propName, string.Empty)
```

and in Script,

```
$("#propName").jStepper({ allowDecimals: false,disableNonNumeric:true,minDecimals: 0, minValue: 1, maxValue: 99, minLength: 2 });
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Post some code that shows how you use jStepper.

Comment: I have added the codes. However, the same is not working even in the official page. http://jstepper.emkay.dk/default.aspx

Comment: Is your call to $("#propName") just an example or is this what you are actually trying to use to select the HTML element? I can safely say that that won't work on jstepper.emkay.dk and most likely it's not how your HTML looks like either. There would have to be an element with an ID of "propName" on the page. Can we see how the HTML looks on the page that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly haven't got any response so far.
But found an alternate approach to solve this by using regular jquery as below.
Hope this will help someone..

```
 $("#id").keyup(function () { 
        var txtelement = $("#id);
        if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '')
        var length = txtelement.val().length;
        var value = txtelement.value;
        if (length > 2) {
            txtelement.value = value.slice(0, length - 1);            
        }
    });
```